# Converting from Styled Components to Material-UI: Can Material use `withStyles()` on a div?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

The logic and operation aspects of my app are untouchable, so I can't go digging into components changing from `<FriendlyComponentName />` to `<div css={{styleObject}} />` via Material `makeStyles()` or whatnot.

Existing Styled Components example:

```
  PageNav: styled.div`
    width: 1440px;
  `,
```

I started with Material `withStyles()` to maintain the component name:

```
  PageNav: withStyles({
    root: {
      width: "1440px",
    },
  })(div)
```

. . . except that, as you see on the last line of the 2nd block, Material doesn't know what to do with  `div` and errors out. Material widgets (`Typography`, etc) work as expected.

Things I've tried putting there:

- Styled Components `styled.div`
- Material `styled("div")`
- just plain `(div)` and `("div")`
- raising the style definition 1 level outside of `root:{}`

The goal is to replace Styled Components definitions with Material UI definitions yet maintain the existing names (like `PageNav` above).

Is it possible to style HTML components like this using Material UI?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the code snippet with replaced Styled Components definitions with Material UI definitions. It also includes an example with redefining CSS property if you decide to tweak a little bit your components while reusing...

```
import "./styles.css";
import { withStyles, createStyles, makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";

const PageNav = withStyles({
  root: {
    width: "1440px",
    height: "80px",
    margin: "0 auto",
    color: "tomato", // default color
    padding: "24px 140px 24px 60px",
    backgroundColor: "white",
    boxSizing: "border-box",
    display: "flex",
    justifyContent: "space-between"
  }
})(({ classes, children }) => <div className={classes.root}>{children}</div>);

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) =>
  createStyles({
    root: {
      color: "blue" // redefined  color
    }
  })
);

export default function App() {
  const classes = useStyles()
  return (
    <PageNav classes={{ root: classes.root }}>
      <ul>
        <li>Item 1</li>
        <li>Item 2</li>
        <li>Item 3</li>
      </ul>
    </PageNav>
  );
}
```

The live example of code snippet is available [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/gifted-golick-fli09?file=/src/App.js:0-843).

Comment: I can't change the component call, so inline `classes` is out... but the rest of it works. Higher up I did `const Div = ({ classes, children }) => <div className={classes.root}>{children}</div>` and then plugged in `PageNav: withStyles({  })(Div),` and it works as expected. Where did you get the idea for the anon function call? I don't think those params is spelled out in material docs. I ***must*** remember that pattern.

Comment: Glad that you found my answer useful! I checked what withStyles function returns and found that it's `PropInjector` which is has a next description `a function that takes {component} and returns a component that passes along all the props to {component} except the {InjectedProps} and will accept additional
{AdditionalProps}`

Comment: WWOOWW. . . I was debating whether or not to implement this across the app, because I have > 100 Styled Component definitions to replace. While it accomplishes the goal of removing Styled lib, it replaces it with a layer of reading complexity. "why the hell did they do that?" with a pretty involved explanation, versus a completely readable `styled.div`. Great answer, and I learned something (the anon func! what they're supposed to be used for!), but I think I'll pass on implementing it.

Comment: In TypeScript, this gives `Property 'classes' does not exist on type 'ConsistentWith<ConsistentWith<{}, { classes: ClassNameMap<"root">; }>, { classes: ClassNameMap<"root">; }>'` and `Property 'children' does not exist on type 'ConsistentWith<ConsistentWith<{}, { classes: ClassNameMap<"root">; }>, { classes: ClassNameMap<"root">; }>'` errors.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to set styles like [this](https://material-ui.com/styles/advanced/#overriding-styles-classes-prop)?
Basically, you create your styles for any elements via `useStyles` and after you can simply use created styles in your code.

Comment: Sorry, I've fixed a link.

Comment: As said on the first line of the post, I can't go into the component logic to change away from `<FriendlyComponent />` in any way.